# Same domain auto login into WebApi using withCredentials

Tags: angular, cors

I have an Angular 7 application set up to fetch data from a WepApi. Both run in the same domain, the API is Asp.Net based. OPTIONS are caught in Application_BeginRequest and accepted, whereas credentials are checked via IIS afterward. So far, everything works.

- The Angular application is served by the IIS using the windows authentication. The auto login works, as expected, in IE/Edge and Chrome. Firefox asks for credentials on the first login.
- The WebApi backend is also served by the IIS in the same domain using windows authentication. The auto login works (when browsing to the API directly), as expected, in IE/Edge and Chrome. Firefox asks for credentials on the first login.

What I can't wrap my head around is this:

- Using the Angular application, I send a HTTP request with "withCredentials: true" to the WebApi. For the first request, ALL browsers ask for windows credentials.

Is there a way to make the auto login work for the CORS call to the WebApi as well? It works fine after entering the credentials once, why doesn't it use the default ones from windows? Is there a way to tell it that I'm calling the same domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out myself. The solution was to use the page url instead of the page IP in the HTTP request from Angular to the backend (as in, "http://myinternalsite/api/" instead of "http://192.168.39.1/api/" as the base url for HTTP requests). Then the browser could correctly identify the target website being within the same domain and automatically used the appropriate credentials instead of prompting the user.